Returning the date-time of the tenth order for every customer on Looker
I have a data table that contains all customer orders along with their order creation date-time. Im currently using Looker, I am trying to achieve a table visualisation that states the customer name and the date-time of the 10th order. The total number of orders made by each customer varies. There are no joins required as all necessary information are in the same data table
I have tried going through LookML (which I think its the only way to achieve this), and did partition by so the orders are grouped by customer names. I'd like to make a comparison of the row number, if its equal to 10, then it'll return the date-time of the specific order. But I realized that I could not filter through numbers are LookML's filter function only accepts string/varchar. I have also tried casting variables to string/varchar, but still it doesn't work. Any possible workarounds? Here is my current LookML code snippet:
dimension: row_num {
    type: number
    sql: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY origin_name ORDER BY order_created_at_myt);;

  }

  dimension_group: tenth_order {
    type: time
    timeframes: [
      raw,
      time_of_day,
      time,
      date,
      week,
      month,
      quarter,
      year
    ]
    datatype: datetime
    sql: ${order_created_at_myt_date}
    filters: [row_num: 10];;
  }


I would add a hidden dimension that checks if the order is 10th
dimension: tenth {
    type: yesno
    hidden: yes
    sql: ${row_num} = 10;;
  }

then change the filter in your dimension group
filters: [tenth: yes]

